# CSS Loading out of Order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently writing an Electron app with Bootstrap css. For whatever reason, bootstrap-theme.min.css is loading before bootstrap.min.css, despite it being in the opposite order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/styles.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/css/tooltip.css">
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="src/img/favicon.ico">
    <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');</script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="src/js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>window.sigma = require('linkurious');</script>
    <script src="node_modules/linkurious/dist/plugins.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/dagre/dist/dagre.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap-3-typeahead/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">
    </div>
    <script>
      (function() {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        if (process.env.ENV === 'development '){
          script.src = 'http://localhost:9000/dist/bundle.js';
        }else{
          script.src = './dist/bundle.js';
        }
        document.write(script.outerHTML);
      }());
    </script>
  </body>

  <script>
    // You can also require other files to run in this process
    require('./renderer.js')
  </script>
</html>
```

As an example, here's the expected output from chrome dev tools when inspecting a button:

[image: Expectation]

And here's what I get instead:

[image: Reality]

Additionally, here's the network tab in dev tools showing the theme file coming first:
[image: Network Tab]

Am I missing something obvious? And is there a workaround to this issue?

Another example, this is on the same app with the same html running outside of electron.

[image: Expected]

And heres inside electron:

[image]

The panel-header style isn't being properly applied by the bootstrap-theme file inside the electron app, while it is outside of Electron.

Comment: you can not switch the loading order? i'am asking this because that would be the obvious thing to do

Comment: I've tried that, and the theme still loads first

Comment: it doesn't matter in which order the browser requests the css, what matters is the order the files are referenced. the latter trumps the former in case of clashes. However, since I'm no mind reader, what exactly is it, that's wrong in your opinion? Which rule / attribute is wrong / not applied / applied?

Comment: If you look at the second screenshot, the bootstrap-theme.min.css rules are being applied BEFORE the bootstrap.min.css rules, which are overriding parts of the css. The theme should be applied last, as is shown in the order of the HTML. The button is just an example, the same thing applies for every other element in my page, leaving elements unstyled since the default bootstrap css is overriding the theme.

The problem is that the order of the files references is not the order in which the css is being applied.

Comment: [Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) is the issue, not the loading order.

Comment: It doesn't look like any styles in bootstrap-theme.min.css are being overridden by bootstrap.min.css. The order of chrome dev tools style elements are from highest priority to lowest, not necessarily the load order.

Comment: I added another example to the post. I understand the priority of styles. I don't understand why my priority would be different inside electron and inside a regular chrome browser. Additionally, the bootstrap css is designed to throw the theme on top of the base file

Answer (score 0):

The reason lies in CSS *specifity*, that's a system ruling the importance/hierarchy of CSS selectors. Simply said, a single class selector will have a lower specifity that a more complex selector consisting of a chain of classes/tags/IDs, which is what happens in your case: `.btn-success` as a selector has a lower specifity than that the selector for that rule listed first in your screenshot, since that one consists of a quite specific chain of selectors which - in combination -  "count more" than a single class.

Here's a helpful article on the subject: https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/

Comment: Why am I getting different results outside of electron using the same 2 stylesheets? The first screenshot in each example is running in chrome, the second screenshot is running inside an electron container.